# Determine whether checkbox was clicked by the user or manually from code

Tags: android, user-interface, checkbox, kotlin

I have multiple *Check Boxes* in an Android activity and I want to implement a tree-like functionality with these Check Boxes.

For example when the user clicks on a checkBox, all sub checkBoxes should also be toggled. Similarly, when all sub checkBoxes are in the same state, the parent checkBox should be notified about this and be toggled accordingly.

In this second case, the parent checkBox will be toggled but should not toggle all the child checkBoxes (because it was not actively clicked by the user but rather toggled as a consequence of all children being toggled)

I toggle the checkBoxes using `checkBox.setChecked(isChecked)`.

This leads to the checkBox's `OnCheckedChangeListener` being called which in turn calls a method responsible for updating all the children.

So I need to find a way to differentiate between user interaction and setting the checkBox state from code.
I tried using `checkBox.setOnClickListener()`, however the onClickListener is always notified **after** the checkBox' state has already changed.

Comment: One can (temporarily) remove the `OnCheckedChangeListener` by calling `checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null); ` Later on you just set the original Listener (which for this purpose should be a field of your Activity or Fragment) once more.

Comment: I don't understand what's the problem with onclick being called after checkbox state changes

Comment: Maybe it would cause an endless loop @Pawel

Comment: @Pawel If it's called afterwards the children are already notified to update which I don't want in this case

Comment: @0X0nosugar Thank you. I thought about doing this and will try it out.

Comment: @jonasstr that's why I personally tend not to use `OnCheckedChangeListener ` at all, I think it's easier to leave only onClick and manually call the update method if you ever modify checked state programatically.